# Extracting Date-stamp from a email subject

Tags: python

Trying a very simple extraction (can be anything), but not able to figure out what the problem is? In the code below I am trying to extract the hour from the date stamp in the email body.

```
txt='From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008'
hr=list()
for line in txt:
    if line.startswith('From '):
        line=line.split()
        hr.append(line[5].split(':')[0])
print(line)
print(hr)
```

it gives me 8 (for print(line) and [] (for print(hr)

I just want to understand why this is not giving the below

> ['From', 'stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za', 'Sat', 'Jan', '5', '09:14:16', '2008']
> ['09']

Comment: txt is a single string. When you write "for line in txt" what you'll get (in line) is each character in the string

Comment: "for line in text" - here, "text" var is string, not list, so you iterate over chars. You should use txt = ["From ..."] instead of txt = "From ...", for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you can be certain about the structure of the string then:-

```
txt = 'From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008'

print(txt.split()[5][:2])
```